# (Opencart) What may be the reasons behind custom module's position not saving in layout?

Tags: opencart

In OC3 (twig) I can't save the custom module's position in the category's layout: when I press save layout and then reopen the category layout, the saved module position disappears. The admin part of the module works (the view works).

I don't even know what I can do to try to fix this, nor have I found any info on the Internet on what I may do here. I have just one item in the language of the catalog controller and I do output that in the twig of the corresponding view if that may make any difference.

This is my module's catalog controller:

```php
    <?php
    class ControllerExtensionModuleProductFilter extends Controller {

    public function index() {
    $this->load->language('extension/module/product_filter');

    if ($setting && $setting['status']) {
    $refresh_products = false;
    $data = array();

    if (isset($this->session->data['refresh_products']) && 
    $this->session->data['refresh_products']) {
    $refresh_products = true;
    }

    if (!isset($this->session->data['refresh_products'])) {
    $refresh_products = true;
    }

    if ($refresh_products) {
    $data['start_product_filter_ajax_session'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/product_filter/startProductFilterAjaxSession');

    return $this->load->view('extension/module/product_filter', $data);
    }
    }
    }

    public function startProductFilterAjaxSession() { //ajax
    $this->session->data['refresh_products'] = $this->request->post['products_refresh_request']; // =? true

    if (isset ($this->session->data['refresh_products']) && ) {
    if ($this->request->post['products_refresh_request'] = $this->session->data['refresh_products']) {
    $this->session->data['refresh_products'] = $this->request->get['products_refresh_request'] ;
    } 
    } else {
    $this->session->data['refresh_products'] = $this->request->post['products_refresh_request'];
    }

    $data = array();
    $data['refresh_needed'] = true;
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/product_filter_session', $data));
    }   
    }
```

I expect that the view twig of the catalog part of the module displays stuff inside "column_left" (for a test sake just a random phrase say). Right now I can't even save the module's layout position.

Comment: It's actually very weird. I came back half an hour later and opened to edit category layout, and the saved module was there, even though after tens of times trying earier it wasn't working. So strange.

Comment: Found out that if I add the module twice to the specific section (left, top, bottom or right) and then save, then if I go back to the layout, the module appears in a single instance in the place where I specified two. If I save only one instance, there is nothing saved. I wonder what's happenning.